# Boxplot with multiple x variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I'm new to R and having a few issues with using `ggplot2`.

This is an example of my data (subset of larger data set) :

```
df <- 
structure(list(logpvalue = c(22.36, 6.93, 16.78, 1.78, 17.75, 
20.99, 21.03, 9.19, 15.01, 22.25, 13.4, 6.47, 1.34, 13.4, 3.21, 
0.37, 0.5, 0.12, 1.8, 0.71, 1.15, 6.73, 0.12, 6.97, 0.64, 9.85, 
1.45, 1.67, 2.6, 1.8, 1.35, 4.69, 0.37, 1.91, 0.31, 0, 2.45, 
1.68, 2.31, 1.35, 6.48, 4.68), SNP = structure(c(1L, 7L, 6L, 
5L, 11L, 1L, 9L, 5L, 8L, 11L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 11L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 
2L, 3L, 10L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 10L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 10L, 4L, 2L, 
3L, 10L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 9L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("rs10244", "rs10891244", 
"rs10891245", "rs11213821", "rs12296076", "rs138567267", "rs45615536", 
"rs6589218", "rs7103178", "rs7127721", "rs7944895"), class = "factor"), 
X173 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("het", "hom"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("logpvalue", 
"SNP", "X173"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -42L))
```

I want to plot a boxplot of `logpvalue` on y axis, with SNP on the x-axis but with each SNP also categorized by whether the patient is `het` or `hom` for `X173`. So from this data I'd imagine 4 boxes on my boxplot.

If possible I'd also like to incorporate the individual data points (dotplot-boxplot overlay) with jitter.

This is the usual code I'd use for a boxplot of logpavlue vs SNP:

```
qplot(logpvalue, SNP, data = mydata, geom="boxplot")
+ geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(w=0.1, h=0.1)) + theme_bw()
```

How do I add the extra x variable into this code?

Comment: Please make your [data reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and read about [box plots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot)

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I've tried to make my data reproducible however its a large dataset and I don't want to paste all my data online. Not sure what your point about boxplots is - I know they are for multiple data points not individual as my previous example data would have given. I barely understand any script so I apologize for my ineptitude!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
boxplot(df$logpvalue~paste(df$SNP,df$X173))
```

Or using `ggolot2` :

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=df,aes(SNP,logpvalue,colour=SNP)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_jitter() +
  facet_grid(.~X173)
```

[image]